# onrejected vs catch in Promise

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

What is the difference between `catch` and `then(_,onRejected)` in `ES6 Promise`? I just know that `onRejected` doesn't handle the rejected state of inner `Promise`.

```
Promise.resolve().then(() => {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
      throw new Error('Error occurs');
    }); 
},er => console.log(er)); //Chrome throws `Uncaught (in promise)`

Promise.resolve().then(() => {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
      throw new Error('Error occurs');
    }); 
}).catch(er => console.log(er)); //Error occurs
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Your first piece of code wont catch the error because the error handler is in the same `.then` where the error is thrown

---

As for your question

```
.catch(onRejected);
```

is identical to

```
.then(null, onRejected);
```

not sure what

```
.then(_, onRejected);
```

would do, depends on what `_` is I guess

Comment: OP wasn't using `_` as a variable name, but to indicate that he was only asking about the second parameter.

Answer (score 1):

In the first example, your `onRejected` applies only to `Promise.resolve()`. In `then(onResolved, onRejected)`, only one of two the function will be called, not both. Try with `Promise.reject('something').then()`, you'll have *something* printed in the console.
The `catch()` applies to the promise you're returning so the Error is caught as expected.